# JS color change for keyboard layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an assignment in school, make a keyboard layout and then change colors of the keys as they're pressed. This means I need to use .keydown .keyup eventListener, etc..

I just need an example code to help me get started.. I'm providing a bit of my code, just so you get the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="keyboard" id="keys">

    <div class="section-a">

        <div class="key tab" id="Tab">

            &#x21e5;

        </div>

        <!-- end of special keys pt.1 -->

        <!-- letter row pt.1 -->

        <div class="key letter" id="KeyQ">
            Q
        </div>

        <div class="key letter" id="KeyW">
            W
        </div>

        <div class="key letter" id="KeyE">
            E
        </div>

        <div class="key letter" id="KeyR">
            R
        </div>

        <div class="key letter" id="KeyT">
            T
        </div>

        <div class="key letter" id="KeyY">
            Y
        </div>

        <div class="key letter" id="KeyU">
            U
        </div>

        <div class="key letter" id="KeyI">
            I
        </div>

        <div class="key letter" id="KeyO">
            O
        </div>

        <div class="key letter" id="KeyP">
            P
        </div>

        <div class="key letter" id="BracketLeft">
            Å
        </div>

        <!--  end of letter row pt.1 -->

        <!-- special keys pt.2 -->

        <div class="key dual" id="BracketRight">
            ^
            <br> ¨
        </div>

    <div class="key enter upper" id="Enter">
        &#8617;
    </div>

    <div class="key caps" id="CapsLock">
        &#8682
    </div>

    <!-- end of special keys pt.2-->
```

Comment: SO is not a homework making service

Comment: Atleast show some javascript code you tried.

Comment: Should the key get back to its previous color after the click or maintain it? If the first case is true, then you won't need JS at all. CSS `:active` class is enough.

Comment: I see that you're a new contributor to Stack Overflow. It's always better here to provide an example of something you tried and didn't work. Don't let the downvote upset you, and good luck on your homework :D

Answer (score 2):

I didn't search for special keys but here is a simple example of how you can change the color of a letter when you press it. Not the best solution but from here you can try more.

```js
var colorMap = {
    'q' : 'blue',
    'w' : 'red',
    'e' : 'yellow'
};

var letterPressed= "";

$(document).on('keyup', function(e){
     var letterMap = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
     var letter = document.getElementById("Key" + letterPressed.toUpperCase() );
     letter.style.color = colorMap[letterMap];
});

document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    letterPressed = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="keyboard" id="keys">
  <div class="section-a">

      <div class="key letter" id="KeyQ"> Q </div>
      <div class="key letter" id="KeyW"> W  </div>
      <div class="key letter" id="KeyE"> E  </div>

      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is I need the physical buttons on my laptop keyboard to trigger the ones I've made in HTML and change their colors.

Comment: Yes, it does that. Click on Run Code snippet, click on the white space where the letters are then press q and the q letter will have a new color xD